# Check for readable files for a directory in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, ls

I'm new with Bash scripting and I've been playing around with it, but I have this script that I doesn't understand:

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in $(ls $HOME)
do
    if [ -f $name -a -r $name ]
    then
        echo "$name is file"
    fi
done
```

If I run it, it prints nothing.
I'm pretty sure that in my home directory I have readable files. Ex:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user user        368 feb 17 22:39 requirements.txt
```

If I test it with another directory, it tells me that I have two files that are readable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  442 jul 27 23:47 longest-and-shortest-username.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 1155 jul 28 00:39 options-for-files-in-directory.sh
```

My Bash version is: 4.2.45(1)-release

Am I loosing something?

Comment: Your script will print the names of regular files whose names have no whitespace and that are readable.  What is your question?

Comment: @John1024 my question is why it's not printing the files that are readable (check for example requirements.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code was trying to get names of files in the HOME directory. But, it was then testing if that name existed in the current directory (which must have been different).

The solution is to attach the directory to the file name.  Try:

```
for name in "$HOME"/*
do
    if [ -f "$name" -a -r "$name" ]
    then
        echo "$name is file"
    fi
done
```

The above has the additional advantage that it will work for file names with spaces and all manor of other hostile characters.

When `bash` sees `$(ls $HOME)`, it runs `ls $HOME` and then applies word splitting to the results.   So, if you have a file named `my file`, `bash` would split it into two arguments `my` and `file`.  You don't want this.  By contrast, when `bash` sees `$HOME/*`, it returns all the file names un-mangled.

Note also that I put double-quotes around `$name` in `[ -f "$name" -a -r "$name" ]`.  This prevents word splitting and assures that this test works properly for all file names.

Comment: +1 - note for all files in the current directory change `for name in $HOME/*` to `for name in *`, file masks work as well e.g. `for name in *.ext`, and you can assign a path to a variable and use that like this `for name in "$DIR_PATH"/*` assuming you have set `DIR_PATH='/path/to/directory'`. HTH.

Comment: Prefer `[ -f "$name" ] && [ -r "$fname" ]` over `-a` (as recommended by the POSIX specification). You don't actually need the `-f`, though; `-r` will check if the file exists in the process of checking if it is readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I was trying the examples in this page: http://pconstantino.wordpress.com/2008/12/14/some-bash-script-exercises/ but it seems that has some problems

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to debug your script so you could identify the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Current directory is $PWD."
echo "HOME is $HOME."
for name in $(ls $HOME)
do
    echo "Checking $file."
    if [ -f $name -a -r $name ]
    then
        echo "$name is file"
    fi
done
```

Here are some tips but please don't modify your script yet until you discover the cause of the problem.

- Enclose your open variables to pairs of double-quotes to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.
- Prefer `[[ ]]` over `[ ]` as it doesn't do word splitting and
  pathname expansion.
- Using `ls` may not be necessary. You can just use `"$HOME"/*`.
- If `ls` is necessary, consider using `while read` loop with process substitution instead: `while IFS= read -r file; do ...; done < <(exec ls -1 "$HOOME")` as it prevents word splitting and pathname expansion. And use `-1` option.